# input onfocus event not detecting html element when reference them by #

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

**Todo :**

- I want to open a date picker "#picker" when its input has focus but it's not working when using onfocus input event and gives an error:

> error :  'picker is not defined'

```
      <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" onfocus="picker.open()"
 placeholder="Choose a date">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
          </mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

but when I did it by a button press it worked

```
<button mat-button (click)="picker.open()">show date picker</button>
```

how can I do this by focusing on an input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Angular [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding):

```
<input ... (focus)="picker.open()" >
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvxfpv?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html) for a demo.

Comment: thank you, can you tell me where is the focus method documented?

Comment: It is the [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Focus_events) HTML DOM event. You can use Angular event binding with the other DOM events as well.